# How to start a web application with Ruby on Rails using AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm about to develop a web application with Ruby on Rails. This should use AJAX and jQuery for better user experience. So my question is, how to start? Should I first develop the basic web application without AJAX requests and then adding AJAX? Or what's the best way?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always develop first without Ajax and test. Then I add the Ajax layer (or Backbone's).

IMHO, it's safer to decouple development this way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it matters as long as you do one or the other only.  Develop the UI including ajax without the services. Or develop the services without the UI.  It might be faster to develop the services first, but I would still find a way to mock them out in your UI code.  You want to be able to test your javascript and services independently.

Answer (score 0):

Worry about your app before you worry about UX, test, build, refactor, test, build refactor ...  Who cares if it looks like crap, just get your app working and write lots and lots of tests.  Then worry about UI and UX and making it all ajaxy